# Line chart not getting displayed properly

Tags: ios, swift, charts, carthage

I am using Charts library for displaying a line-chart in my app.
For some reason, I have used Carthage method to integrate the Charts framework into my app.

However, the chart is not displaying correctly when there's only two points available, otherwise the points are displayed properly.

Also I have researched for similar issue on this platform, but had no luck. Not sure why is this happening ?

See the attached screenshots below. Thanks in advance.

**Chart with two points will display like following one -**

[image: chart-issue]

**Chart with three or more points will display like following one -**

[image: chart-more-points]

Comment: are you using this one.? https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Comment: @BenRockey Yes, I am using the same library.

Answer (score 1):

**Check This..**
[image]

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class LineChartViewController: UIViewController, ChartViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var lineChartVw: LineChartView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        lineChartVw.delegate = self
        lineChartVw.chartDescription?.enabled = false
        lineChartVw.dragEnabled = true
        lineChartVw.setScaleEnabled(true)
        lineChartVw.pinchZoomEnabled = true
        lineChartVw.legend.enabled = false
        lineChartVw.drawBordersEnabled = true

        self.setDataCount(Int(2), range: UInt32(5))

        lineChartVw.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
        lineChartVw.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
        lineChartVw.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
        lineChartVw.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
        lineChartVw.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom

    }


    func setDataCount(_ count: Int, range: UInt32) {
        let values = (0..<count).map { (i) -> ChartDataEntry in
            return ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(i), icon:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "round1"))
        }

        let set1 = LineChartDataSet(values: values, label: "DataSet 1")
        set1.drawIconsEnabled = false
        set1.setColor(.black)
        set1.setCircleColor(.black)
        set1.lineWidth = 1
        set1.circleRadius = 3
        set1.valueFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 9)
        set1.drawFilledEnabled = true

        let data = LineChartData(dataSet: set1)

        lineChartVw.data = data
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for the response Ben. The points are displayed in chart correctly, only the area below that line is filling partially, rest everything is working fine.

Comment: just add.        set1.drawFilledEnabled = true